Facing issues in AWS and Guava jars when deploying the application in Liberty
We are in the verge of deploying our web application in higher version of WebSphere Liberty in order to support jdk 17.
When we scanned our ear using binaryAppScanner.jar, it reported some issues in the below mentioned jars. These jars needs to be replaced/removed. Is there any replacement for these jars so that it supports jdk 17?

aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.583.jar
guava-32.0.1-jre.jar

Kindly guide. TIA.
